# $L^P$ spaces inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I would like to prove:

Suppose $X\subset\mathbb{R}^m$  and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are measurable sets, and $1\leq p\leq \infty.$ Show that if $f(x,y):X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$  is measurable and nonnegative, then
$$\left\|\int_Y f(x,y)dy\right\|_{L^P(X)}\leq \int_Y\|f(x,y)\|_{L^P(X)}dy$$

I would greatly appreciate a hint to prove this result.
I tried to use the theorem that if $$\sup\left\{\int_E fg:g\in L^q(E),\|g\|_L^q(E)\leq1\right\} \leq M <\infty,$$ then $f\in L^P(E)$ and $\|f\|_{L^P(E)}\leq M.$ But I can't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: You can find the proof [here](http://calclab.math.tamu.edu/~sivan/math663_08a/appendix2.pdf)

Comment: Similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58194/minkowskis-inequality)

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=\infty$, using Jensen inequality we get:
$$
\left\|\int_Y f(x,y)dy\right\|_{L{(X)}^\infty}=\sup_X\left|\int_Yf(x,y)dy \right|\le\sup_X\int_Y\left|f(x,y)\right|dy\le\int_Y\sup_X\left|f(x,y)\right|dy=\int_Y\left\|f \right\|_{L{(X)}^\infty}.
$$
The case $1\le p< \infty $ is given in a comment to the question.

Comment: It looks like you have missed some power $p$ (or $1/p$ resp.) in your estimations.

Comment: @Nyfiken , you are right. I am thinking how to correct the inequalities. Feel free to correct if you already know how!

Comment: I do not know a short proof. I gave two links above in the comment under OP that have some suggestions.

Comment: Edited my answer